# After accessing certain data, internet cuts out for all devices on network switch

Tags: networking, switch

This is hard to describe, so I'll try to be thorough. Not sure if this is the correct site to ask this, this question was put on hold as off topic in Server Fault.

My setup is that I have a small network switch (1GBPS) in order to be able to wire in my home PC and my work PC for a better connection.

When I access a certain page on the web app I'm working on with my work pc, both my home PC and my work PC completely lose all internet connection for 30 seconds to a minute. The only error I get in my code is a timeout because the connection drops. The page it tends to happen on is a page that loads a customer's order. It tends to happen most consistently when I do a cache refresh. On a hard refresh, chrome dev tools reports 2.3 MB of data transferred in the network tab. While this is a decent size, it's not some huge payload that my switch can't handle.

I'm a ASP.NET developer, so I'm not doing anything crazy with the internet connection (i.e. i'm not writing my own network code that could be tanking it), just using built-in ASP.NET libraries. It does seem to happen more consistently when doing a hard-refresh (CTRL+F5 in chrome) than on a normal refresh.

I have two work PCs, as we're in transition from a win7 machine to a win10 machine. I have never experienced this with the win7 machine, only the win10. My machine is on 1803 windows 10 build.

What is something that could potentially cause this problem? I don't know where to look first. I know our win10 PCs have new kinds of group policies on them that could be the cause, but I'd like to try to steer our IT team towards finding this as they wouldn't be able to reproduce the issue easily.

Comment: "Home PC" and "IT team"? Does that mean you're bringing your work PC home somehow? Do you use any sort of VPN anywhere? Does this keep happening if you remove the switch and connect a computer directly to the uplink? If you're not using a VPN (just direct internet access), do you have admin access to the router and does it have any sort of "intrusion detection" feature?

Comment: Yes work laptop uses a VPN. The whole router doesn't stop, as my phone on wifi is still able to access the internet while this is happening